# Magento - I get "Undefined rate from GBP-USD" when doing currencyConvert

Tags: magento

I am trying to do:

```
$amount = Mage:helper('directory')->currencyConvert($amount,$fromCurrency,$toCurrency);
```

It is working fine when the "Base Currency: USD" and "Default Display Currency: EUR", but when I replace "EUR" with "GBP" I get this exception:
"Undefined rate from GBP-USD" when doing currencyConvert

Both EUR and GBP rates exist.

Answer (score 1):

Dayna,You was not properly configure currencies. Please select multiple currencies from admin>
system>configuration and also, setting the currency rate from admin>manage currency>

Comment: I did select USD,EUR and GBP from:
System -> configuration -> currency setup
and add currency rates in system -> currency setup
What I miss??

Answer (score 0):

In Magento you cannot convert "Your Currency" to the "Base Currency".

See these answers from WaPoNe for more details and possible solution.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34548/currency-convertor

[magento - convert order amount from current currency to base currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852882/magento-convert-order-amount-from-current-currency-to-base-currency)